# Flutter render conditionally

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, rendering

I wanna render my home page based on the value of the current user occupation in the firestore if the variable equal seller i render the HomeSeller() else if its client i render the other page HomeClient else i return an error or  in my firestore i got a collection of users that contains the users identified with email (doc) and every user got first name last name and occupation fields.
how can i do this conditional rending

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'package:auth_app/pages/home_page.dart';
import 'package:auth_app/pages/Login_or_register_page.dart';

class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const Wrapper({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            //user is logged in:
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return const Home();
            }
            //user is NOT logged in:
            else {
              return const LoginOrRegister();
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

i wanna to do the conditional rending instead of rendering the Home

Comment: Without repeating the use-case: what isn't working about the code you shared? Is there an error message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The code is working as it is but i wanna add a conditional rending of my Home page based on an data in my Firestore i didn't know how to reach the field to check the written data then return HomeClient() or HomeSeller() in the place of the Home()
now its working and render the Home page when the user is already connected if not it will show the Login page now i just wanna improve it and after checking that the user is existing check his occupation in the Firestore and return his provided page.